# Unable to test MutationObserver observe() callback

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mutation-observers

I'm using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect changes in a DOM element using Angular. Everything is working as expected, but my issue now is how to test if the MutationObserver `observe()` callback is called.

This is my current Jest test file:

```
describe('MutationObserverDemoComponent', () => {
  let component: MutationObserverDemoComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MutationObserverDemoComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MutationObserverDemoComponent]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MutationObserverDemoComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    
    const mutationObserverMock = jest.fn<MutationObserver, [MutationCallback]>().mockImplementation(() => ({
      observe: jest.fn(),
      disconnect: jest.fn(),
      takeRecords: jest.fn()
    }));
    global.MutationObserver = mutationObserverMock;
  });

  it('should observe DOM changes', () => {
    const target = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.mutation-div')).nativeElement;

    let observedMutations: MutationRecord[] = [];
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations: MutationRecord[]) => {
      console.log('I am not called!'); // this is never called
      observedMutations = observedMutations.concat(mutations);
    });

    observer.observe(target, { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true });

    target.setAttribute('data-mutation', 'testing'); // this should trigger the MutationObserver
    expect(observedMutations.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });
});
```

For some reason, the `observe()` callback isn't being called even though the DOM element is changed.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Is this [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Taking a step back, all this test does is check whether a built-in functionality works. It should only fail when a) the test isn't setup correctly (might be the issue here) or b) the vanilla implementation changes. The latter shouldn't really happen and binding functionality outside your application in tests is basically useless. At best, it tells you that something that shouldn't happen has happened. But should be easy to verify by essentially *nothing working*.

Comment: @vlaz What I'm trying to figure out is if it's possible to test the DOM changes in this specific scenario and, if yes, am I doing it correctly. Are you saying that I shouldn't do such tests? Is this a bad pattern?

Comment: It's a bad pattern to test external functionality. In this case `MutationObserver` but also anything that comes from third party libraries, for example. If you need to check if the callback to `MutationObserver` behaves how you expect, you don't *need* `MutationObserver`. You need *the callback*. Because that's where the logic is. In the test you'd do `cb()` to trigger it and assert it does what you expect. All the observer does is trigger the callback under some conditions.

Comment: If you need to check whether it's triggered appropriately that's 1. a separate test 2. you wouldn't test it by setting up the observer *in the test*. Because that's circular - you're testing whether the test does what the test is doing.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for the explanations. I'm going to skip the test on the `MutationObserver`. Just out of curiosity, how would I test the callback based on my current solution?

Comment: I assume you have some real code which defines the callback. Export it and then import it in the test. Then you can use it like you would any other imported function. It's not at all different to how you'd write any other unit test. You might need to take care to execute the callback correctly (so, pass in mutation records if that's what it expects) but it's again not different to how you'd test any other function that accepts some data and does stuff. Then check it did what you expect. Yet again - not different to any other test.